# when application run on emulator  it stays blank and i am using android emulator 2.1 api level 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

- Android Launch!
- WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
  -[  Device API version is 7 (Android 2.1-update1)
  -[  Uploading project.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
- [  Failed to install project]
- .apk on device 'emulator-5556': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
- [  java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
- [ Launch canceled!
- [ SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8': Unable to find base platform with API level '8'
- [- SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8-1': Unable to find base platform with API level '8'
- [ SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon_google_apis_google_inc_11': Unable to find base platform with API level '11'
- [ SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-3': Unable to find base platform with API level '3'
- [- SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-4': Unable to find base platform with API level '4'
- [ - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-5_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '5'
- [ - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-6_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '6'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't just dump errors here. Describe your problem, what you've done so far to fix it, and the resolts of your efforts. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement! - 
please check your manifest file you didn't write the solution for that like:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

It will use to target particular Android version (API Level )  as per your application requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Set the proper `minSdkVersion` for your app in the

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"/>
```

tag of your manifest, where "integer" is the API level of your app.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) for more details.